Why is TMR0 not producing an accurate waveform period?
I am using TMR0 to generate a more controlled square waveform. The internal osc is 16 MHz. The instruction execution should be 4 MHz so I am expecting a period of 0.25us but am not getting anything near that. I commented out parts of a previous code i got from a youtube video. Here is my code:
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function 
//on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code 
//protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or 
//oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)


#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config STVREN = OFF     // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or 
//Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage 
//(Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming 
//enabled)

#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000

//#define LED        PORTCbits.RC0       //Create meaningful names for our pins
//#define LED_TRIS   TRISCbits.TRISC0
//#define LED2       PORTCbits.RC2
//#define LED2_TRIS  TRISCbits.TRISC2

//volatile unsigned int idleCounter = 0;

//void interrupt external()
//{
//reset the interrupt flag
//INTCONbits.INTF = 0
//if(INTCONbits.TMR0IF){  // check if its a Timer0 interrupt
    //INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;  //clear the interrupt flag
    //TMR0 =50;   //reload Timer0 to generate interrupt every 1 second 
    //idleCounter++;  //Increment the idle counter
    
//}

//if(INTCONbits.INTF){ //check if its an external interrupt (button press)
   // __delay_ms(10);
    //INTCONbits.INTF = 0; //clear the interrupt flag
    
    //idleCounter = 0; //reset idle counter
    
    //LED = ~LED; //flip the bit
     
   //}
   
       
//}

void main(void){
    TRISA = 0xFF;   //set all digital I/O to inputs
    TRISC = 0xFF;

    ANSELA = 0x00;  //disable all analog ports
    ANSELC = 0x00;

//OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0;     // Prescaler is assigned to Timer0
//OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b111;  // Prescaler is 256
// OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0;

//TMR0 = 6;             //Load Timer0 to generate interrupt every 1 second (adjust for your 
//clock)
//INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;  //Enable Timer0 interrupt
//INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;  //Clear Timer0 interrupt flag 

//LED_TRIS = 0;   //LED is an output
//LED2_TRIS = 0;

//INTCONbits.INTF = 0;        //reset the external interrupt flag
//OPTION_REGbits.INTEDG = 1;  //interrupt on the rising edge
// INTCONbits.INTE = 1;        //enable the external interrupt
//INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         //set the Global Interrupt Enable
TRISA2 = 0;  // Set RC2 as output
OPTION_REGbits.TMR0CS = 0;
OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0;
OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b000;
TMR0 = 255;
INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;
INTCONbits.GIE = 1;




 while(1){
    
    //LED2 = ~LED2;
    //__delay_ms(10);
    //LED2= ~LED2;
    //__delay_ms(10);
    //if(idleCounter >= 10){
        //idleCounter = 0;
        //LED2=0;
        //LED=0;
        //SLEEP();   
    //}
    //if (TMR0 >= 2) { // TMR0 overflows after ~1ms with prescaler = 8
        //LATA2 = ~LATA2; // Toggle RC2
       // TMR0 = 0;       // Reset Timer0
    //}
    
 }


 return;
}

void __interrupt() isr(void){
 if(INTCONbits.TMR0IF){
    PORTAbits.RA2 ^= 1;
    TMR0 = 255;
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;
    
 }
}


Which exactly type of PIC you are using?

The interrupt code is executed by the CPU.
Each opcode takes 0.25 microseconds to execute, and the interrupt code is many opcodes.
If you trigger an interrupt to happen every 0.25 microseconds, your CPU cannot execute the amount of code required in 0.25 microseconds.
It also takes some CPU cycles for the CPU to switch to execute the interrupt context and return from it.

I see. How do i calculate the fastest period i can execute then? I used a preload value of 254 since TMR0 is 8 bits. This means it is only has a count of 1 before it resets. The way i understood it was that Tperiod=Tclkprescaler(256-preload value) but if what you're saying is true then this relationship only holds up to a certain preload value or prescaler value.

interrupt latency is three or four instruction cycles...added to instruction inside the interrupt service routine. So I'd guess you should try decreasing your preload value to something lower than about 245 (decimal) if TMR0 prescaler is 1:1

@xcaliber99 You need to see how long your interrupt code takes to run and that's the fastest it can do. It is in no relation that the timer can be programmed to do interrupts faster than the CPU can handle them, you as the programmer are responsible for doing things that are possible. In some MCUs you don't only generate interrupts but let a timer generate PWM in hardware without generating interrupts.

i tested it with an oscilloscope and i am getting 2.15kHz. this is too low.
